# Masterpage on visual studio coming up with "System" Error (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, master-pages

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Farmshop : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

(Error  1   Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute, and that it extends the correct base class (e.g. Page or UserControl). C:\Users\Molo\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\WebSites\www.up647529farmshop.co.uk\Farmshop.master.cs   8   33  www.up647529farmshop.co.uk )

Comment: What does you master page definition look like?

Answer (score 0):

In your masterpage at the first line (usually) you find the following decleration:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" MasterPageFile="~/my.master" %>
```

Check the value of the attribute `Inherits` and make sure it maches your class name. In your case it should be `Farmshop`

```
Inherits="Farmshop"
```

Comment: Hey thanks for answering but I checked my inherits and I have that as "FarmShop" but the error still persists for some reason!

Comment: It should be "Farmshop" and not "FarmShop". Class names are case sensitive